# Installed apache open office and uninstalled it and it has killed my day

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, libreoffice

Hello guys so i tried installing apache open office and thus had to first uninstall libre office but after realising it was fake i again tried to install libre office which i did with snap but whenever i try installing other stuff or even upgrading my packages, i get the following errors;
forexample;

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:6.2.2) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-java-common : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-report-builder : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-script-provider-bsh : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-script-provider-js : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-script-provider-python : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-style-colibre : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-style-elementary : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-style-tango : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

..........................

```
sudo apt-get purge wps-office
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:6.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-java-common : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-report-builder : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-script-provider-bsh : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-script-provider-js : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-script-provider-python : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-style-colibre : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-style-elementary : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-style-tango : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: on the 2nd one, i was trying to remove wps office coz i also installed it about 2 days ago and it just never opens.

Comment: Everything is just straining my nerve right now

Comment: Have you tried what it suggests? You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:

Comment: i tried but the same error is shown

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is due to broken installs or unmet dependencies which could have resulted from broken uninstallation of the sayed packages.

Please run

```
apt-get autoremove
apt-get autoclean
apt-get -f install
apt-get --fix-broken install
dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
```

`apt-get autoremove`
The autoremove option removes packages that were automatically installed because some other package required them but, with those other packages removed, they are no longer needed.

`apt-get autoclean`
The apt-get autoclean option, like apt-get clean, clears the local repository of retrieved package files, but it only removes files that can no longer be downloaded and are virtually useless. It helps to keep your cache from growing too large.

`apt-get -f install` and `apt-get --fix-broken install`
The `-f` means fix and the command is used to fix broken installs.

I hope this helps.